# c# POST json not working as expected?

Tags: c#, python, json

I have this example python script that im trying to convert to c# using newtonsoft :

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json
url = 'http://server.net/fcgi/scrut_fcgi.fcgi'
report_details = {
'reportTypeLang' : 'conversations',
'reportDirections' : {
'selected' : 'inbound'
},
'times' : {
'dateRange' : 'Last5Minutes'
},
'filters' : {
'sdfDips_0' : 'in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410'
},
'dataGranularity' : {
'selected' : 'auto'
}
}
data_i_need = {
'inbound' : {
'table' : {
'query_limit' : {
'offset' : 0,
'max_num_rows' : 1
}
}
},
'outbound' : {
'table' : {
'query_limit' : {
'offset' : 0,
'max_num_rows' : 1
}
}
}
}
data = {
'rm' : 'report_api',
'action' : 'get',
'rpt_json' : json.dumps( report_details ),
'data_requested' : json.dumps( data_i_need )
}

data = urllib.urlencode( data )
req = urllib2.Request( url, data )
response = urllib2.urlopen( req )   
report = response.read()
report_obj = json.loads( report )
```

so far with some help i have the following c# code but it does not return any data like the python version just errors as if the request is incorrect:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReportDirections reportDirections = new ReportDirections();
        reportDirections.selected = "inbound";

        Times Times = new Times();
        Times.dateRange = "Last5Minutes";

        Filters Filters = new Filters();
        Filters.sdfDips_0 = "in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410";

        DataGranularity DataGranularity = new DataGranularity();
        DataGranularity.selected = "auto";

        ReportDetails ReportDetails = new ReportDetails();
        ReportDetails.reportTypeLang = "conversations";
        ReportDetails.reportDirections = reportDirections;
        ReportDetails.times = Times;
        ReportDetails.filters = Filters;
        ReportDetails.dataGranularity = DataGranularity;
        //
        QueryLimit QueryLimit = new QueryLimit();
        QueryLimit.offset = 0;
        QueryLimit.max_num_rows = 1;

        QueryLimit2 QueryLimit2 = new QueryLimit2();
        QueryLimit2.offset = 0;
        QueryLimit2.max_num_rows = 1;

        Table Table = new Table();
        Table.query_limit = QueryLimit;

        Table2 Table2 = new Table2();
        Table2.query_limit = QueryLimit2;

        Inbound Inbound = new Inbound();
        Inbound.table = Table;

        Outbound Outbound = new Outbound();
        Outbound.table = Table2;

        DataINeed DataINeed = new DataINeed();
        DataINeed.inbound = Inbound;
        DataINeed.outbound = Outbound;

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://server.bobo.net/fcgi/scrut_fcgi.fcgi");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            using (var tw = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(tw,
                    new
                    {
                        action = "get",
                        rm = "report_api",
                        data_requested = DataINeed,
                        rpt_json = ReportDetails
                    });
            }
        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseText);
        }
    }
}
public class tw
{
    public string rm { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string rpt_json { get; set; }
    public string data_requested { get; set; }
}
public class DataINeed
{
    public Inbound inbound { get; set; }
    public Outbound outbound { get; set; }
}
public class Inbound
{
    public Table table { get; set; }
}
public class Outbound
{
    public Table2 table { get; set; }
}
public class Table
{
    public QueryLimit query_limit { get; set; }
}
public class Table2
{
    public QueryLimit2 query_limit { get; set; }
}
public class QueryLimit
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int max_num_rows { get; set; }
}
public class QueryLimit2
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int max_num_rows { get; set; }
}
public class ReportDetails
{
    public string reportTypeLang { get; set; }
    public ReportDirections reportDirections { get; set; }
    public Times times { get; set; }
    public Filters filters { get; set; }
    public DataGranularity dataGranularity { get; set; }
}
public class ReportDirections
{
    public string selected { get; set; }
}
public class Times
{
    public string dateRange { get; set; }
}
public class Filters
{
    public string sdfDips_0 { get; set; }
}

public class DataGranularity
{
    public string selected { get; set; }
}
public class bob
{

}
```

does this look like the correct way to POST the json request or does something look wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;  
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReportDirections reportDirections = new ReportDirections();
        reportDirections.selected = "inbound";

        Times Times = new Times();
        Times.dateRange = "Last5Minutes";

        Filters Filters = new Filters();
        Filters.sdfDips_0 = "in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410";

        DataGranularity DataGranularity = new DataGranularity();
        DataGranularity.selected = "auto";

        ReportDetails ReportDetails = new ReportDetails();
        ReportDetails.reportTypeLang = "conversations";
        ReportDetails.reportDirections = reportDirections;
        ReportDetails.times = Times;
        ReportDetails.filters = Filters;
        ReportDetails.dataGranularity = DataGranularity;
        //
        QueryLimit QueryLimit = new QueryLimit();
        QueryLimit.offset = 0;
        QueryLimit.max_num_rows = 1;

        QueryLimit2 QueryLimit2 = new QueryLimit2();
        QueryLimit2.offset = 0;
        QueryLimit2.max_num_rows = 1;

        Table Table = new Table();
        Table.query_limit = QueryLimit;

        Table2 Table2 = new Table2();
        Table2.query_limit = QueryLimit2;

        Inbound Inbound = new Inbound();
        Inbound.table = Table;

        Outbound Outbound = new Outbound();
        Outbound.table = Table2;

        DataINeed DataINeed = new DataINeed();
        DataINeed.inbound = Inbound;
        DataINeed.outbound = Outbound;

        WebClient _webClient = new WebClient();
        _webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        string data_requested = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataINeed));
        string rpt_json = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ReportDetails));

        string data = "action=get&rm=report_api&data_requested=" + data_requested + "&rpt_json="+rpt_json;

        string address = "http://server/fcgi/scrut_fcgi.fcgi";
        var responseText = Encoding.Default.GetString(_webClient.UploadData(address, "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data)));
        Console.WriteLine(responseText);
    }
}
public class tw
{
    public string rm { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string rpt_json { get; set; }
    public string data_requested { get; set; }
}
public class DataINeed
{
    public Inbound inbound { get; set; }
    public Outbound outbound { get; set; }
}
public class Inbound
{
    public Table table { get; set; }
}
public class Outbound
{
    public Table2 table { get; set; }
}
public class Table
{
    public QueryLimit query_limit { get; set; }
}
public class Table2
{
    public QueryLimit2 query_limit { get; set; }
}
public class QueryLimit
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int max_num_rows { get; set; }
}
public class QueryLimit2
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int max_num_rows { get; set; }
}
public class ReportDetails
{
    public string reportTypeLang { get; set; }
    public ReportDirections reportDirections { get; set; }
    public Times times { get; set; }
    public Filters filters { get; set; }
    public DataGranularity dataGranularity { get; set; }
}
public class ReportDirections
{
    public string selected { get; set; }
}
public class Times
{
    public string dateRange { get; set; }
}
public class Filters
{
    public string sdfDips_0 { get; set; }
}

public class DataGranularity
{
    public string selected { get; set; }
}
public class bob
{

}
```

Comment: Still returns the same result as above, looking with wireshark the c# request looks like this: `{"action":"get","rm":"report_api","data_requested":{"inbound":{"table":{"query_limit":{"offset":0,"max_num_rows":1}}},"outbound":{"table":{"query_limit":{"offset":0,"max_num_rows":1}}}},"rpt_json":{"reportTypeLang":"conversations","reportDirections":{"selected":"inbound"},"times":{"dateRange":"Last5Minutes"},"filters":{"sdfDips_0":"in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410"},"dataGranularity":{"selected":"auto"}}}` and the py looks like see next comment....

Comment: `action=get&rm=report_api&data_requested=%7B%22inbound%22%3A+%7B%22table%22%3A+%7B%22query_limit%22%3A+%7B%22max_num_rows%22%3A+1%2C+%22offset%22%3A+0%7D%7D%7D%2C+%22outbound%22%3A+%7B%22table%22%3A+%7B%22query_limit%22%3A+%7B%22max_num_rows%22%3A+1%2C+%22offset%22%3A+0%7D%7D%7D%7D&rpt_json=%7B%22reportDirections%22%3A+%7B%22selected%22%3A+%22inbound%22%7D%2C+%22dataGranularity%22%3A+%7B%22selected%22%3A+%22auto%22%7D%2C+%22reportTypeLang%22%3A+%22conversations%22%2C+%22filters%22%3A+%7B%22sdfDips_0%22%3A+%22in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410%22%7D%2C+%22times%22%3A+%7B%22dateRange%22%3A+%22Last5Minute`

Comment: not sure if that makes any difference with the py request being applicatio/x-www-form-urlencoded and the c# being application/json ?

Comment: also try..
string address = "http://gh-scr-d01.diti.lr.net/fcgi/scrut_fcgi.fcgi"+"?"+data;
 var responseText = Encoding.Default.GetString(_webClient.DownloadData(address));

if previous updtate does't work

Comment: looking at the original py formed request it seems to enclose the sections in single quotes for data requested and rpt_json : `{'action': 'get', 'rm': 'report_api', 'data_requested': '{"inbound": {"table": {"query_limit": {"max_num_rows": 1, "offset": 0}}}, "outbound": {"table": {"query_limit": {"max_num_rows": 1, "offset": 0}}}}', 'rpt_json': '{"reportDirections": {"selected": "inbound"}, "dataGranularity": {"selected": "auto"}, "reportTypeLang": "conversations", "filters": {"sdfDips_0": "in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410"}, "times": {"dateRange": "Last5Minutes"}}'}` but the c# does not?

Comment: ignore the above single quote thing in the transmitted request the only difference i can see is the py version has extra spaces im guessing why they only gave a py and js example :) maybe as a cop out i could call the python from c# the parse the results :)

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it working by changing the content-type to :

```
_webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

i was debugging with charles and the python version was posting a json formated form, changed the c# content type to match and now works a treat

Many Thanks for your code and help.